# LINQ Array Insert into Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to download an array of strings into a field in my database. For some reason instead of auto-incrementing, I'm duplicating my input for some reason.

I get the error message

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__ceArea__4FDBB1FDFC286D16'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ceArea'. The duplicate key
>   value is (0).

Code is below.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
   //Selected checkbox areas

        IEnumerable<string> allChecked = (from item in ceCheckBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                       where item.Selected
                                       select item.Value);


        string[] selectedAreaValues = allChecked.ToArray();
```

I insert the array into DB in this code.

```
ceArea ceArea = new ceArea();

        foreach (string area in selectedAreaValues)
        {

                 OdContext.ceAreas.InsertOnSubmit(new ceArea() { AreaName = area });
        }
```

This is the only thing I can't get into my DB.

Comment: "For some reason instead of auto-incrementing,", What is the primary key in your table, It looks like `AreaName` is the primary key. If you have an integer field as primary key then you have to set Identity specifications and then you can expect Auto increment.

Comment: Thanks Habib. I was going to save the array in a field but just decided to go with a junction table for my many to many relationship. I just wanted to say I appreciate the answer.